# Idiomatic Go equivalent to subclasses

Tags: c++, design-patterns, go

I have a lot more experience in C++ than Go. I'm trying to understand how the [Composite design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite) is expressed idiomatically in Go, in particular with reference to attributes. In C++, I'd use a parent class to hold attributes and methods that are common to a set of subclasses. I'm not seeing how this works in Go. An interface lets me define which methods to implement, but it doesn't let me provide a default implementation. I have to reimplement the method in every struct that implements the interface, and replicate all of the attributes in each struct. I can't keep common attributes in an interface, because interfaces don't have data elements. How do you do this sort of refactoring in Go?

Here's an example (in C++) of what I'd like to be able to do in Go:

```
#include <string>

/*
 * Parent class for edible things. Holds the "name" attribute.
 */

class Edible {
public:
        Edible(const std::string &aName):
                ed_Name(aName) { }
        const std::string &name() const { return ed_Name; }

protected:
        void setName(const std::string &aName) { ed_Name = aName; }

private:
        std::string ed_Name;
};

/*
 * Subclass of Edible for fruits. Depends on Edible to store the name.
 */

class Fruit: public Edible {
public:
        Fruit(const std::string &aName,
              const std::string &aPlant):
                Edible(aName),
                fr_Plant(aPlant) { }
        const std::string &plant() const { return fr_Plant; }

protected:
        void setPlant(const std::string &aPlant) { fr_Plant = aPlant; }

private:
        std::string fr_Plant;
};

/*
 * Subclass of Edible for meats. Depends on Edible to store the name.
 * Has attributes for the animal and the cut of meat.
 */

class Meat: public Edible {
public:
        Meat(const std::string &aName,
             const std::string &aAnimal,
             const std::string &aCut):
                Edible(aName),
                me_Animal(aAnimal),
                me_Cut(aCut) { }
        const std::string &animal() const { return me_Animal; }
        const std::string &cut() const { return me_Cut; }
protected:
        void setAnimal(const std::string &aAnimal) { me_Animal = aAnimal; }
        void setCut(const std::string &aCut) { me_Cut = aCut; }
private:
        std::string me_Animal;
        std::string me_Cut;
};
```

Comment: Go does not have inheritance, so type hierarchies are usually something you want to avoid. C++/Java design patterns don't fit well to the structural types and composition used in Go.

Comment: Do a search for embedding in Go and read up on the recommended design patterns. As JimB said you'll want to rethink the design a little, the simplest way from me to describe it is that the inheritance relationship is inverted. You never inherit, you only compose/embed. In addition to that, when you'd achieve polymorphic behavior using a parent type like iterating `[]ParentType` and calling `MethodThatsOverriden()` instead you'll need to define an interface and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, you could have an `Edible` interface, and `type Fruit struct` and `type Meat struct` which each implemented them. Each of those could also be composed such that it contained an `EdibleName` which would provide the methods and storage space to set / get the name.

e.g.

```
type Edible interface {
    eat() int // common method
}

type EdibleName struct {
    name string
}

// NB getters and setters may not be idiomatic
func (n *EdibleName) getName() string {
    return n.name
}

func (n *EdibleName) setName(name string) {
    n.name = name
}

type Fruit struct {
    pips int
    EdibleName
}

func (f *Fruit) eat() int {
    // ...
    return 0
}

type Meat struct {
    animal int
    EdibleName
}

func (m *Meat) eat() int {
    animal int
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Would this allow me to, for example, have a list of Edibles, and retrieve the name of each instance without worrying about whether it's a Fruit or a Meat? I presume that adding GetName() to the Edible interface would do this, correct?

Comment: If you wanted to do it that way, yes you'd need to add `GetName()` to the editable interface. Or perhaps simply something that returned a pointer to `EditableName` or whatever you have your common stuff in (`EdibleItem` perhaps).

Comment: In the actual implementation, I have more than one way for the top level interface to access the values of the attributes, so a method is definitely the way to go. Thanks much for the answer. This is just what I was missing. I knew it couldn't be the case that Go doesn't provide a mechanism something this fundamental.